# unable to download the image in jpeg format in mobile device (android/ios) but it works in desktop with same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an image with 2 download buttons below  that image download, 1st is for png format and 2nd one is for jpeg everything is working fine on the desktop but in the mobile browser 2nd button is not working as expected as when I try to click and download as a jpeg then the downloaded one with png format

``  const handleDownload = (downloadFormat) => {
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = data.qrCode;

```
if (downloadFormat === "png") {
  link.download = "qrcode.png";
} else if (downloadFormat === "jpeg") {
  link.download = "qrcode.jpeg";
}


if ('toBlob' in HTMLCanvasElement.prototype) {
  // If supported, fetch the QR code and convert it to a blob
  fetch(data.qrCode)
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
      // Create a temporary URL for the image blob
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      link.href = blobUrl;
       link.click();

      URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
    });
} else {
  // If the browser does not support toBlob, fallback to a simple download
  link.click();
}
```

};``